# What's the most idiomatic way to make a collection of enum.Enum in Python?

Tags: python, enum, idioms

I have an Enum in Python that looks something like this:

```
import enum

class Color(enum.Enum):
    red = 'red'
    blue = 'blue'
    yellow = 'yellow'
    puce = 'puce'
    chartreuse = 'chartreuse'
```

And I *want* to have something like:

```
primary_colors = (Color.red, Color.blue, Color.yellow)
```

But naturally if I try and stick that line in the enum, `Color` is not defined. And if I use `(red, blue, yellow)` then it becomes just a tuple of strings. And I can't extend Enum, so I can't do something like:

```
class PrimaryColor(enum.Enum):
    red = 'red'
    yellow = 'yellow'
    green = 'green'

class Color(enum.Enum, PrimaryColor):
    puce = 'puce'
    chartreuse = 'chartreuse'
```

So what's an idiomatic sort of way that I can say that I have this collection of primary colors that's a subset of `Color`? Am I limited to something like this?

```
primary_colors = (Color.red, Color.yellow, Color.blue)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471864/enum-of-enums-in-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the things to keep in mind about `enum.Enum` is that any non-[`descriptor`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) attribute is converted into an `Enum` member -- so `property` and functions/methods are not (converted).  This means you can do something like:

```
class Color(enum.Enum):
    red = 'red'
    blue = 'blue'
    yellow = 'yellow'
    puce = 'puce'
    chartreuse = 'chartreuse'

    @property
    def primary_colors(self):
        return self.red, self.blue, self.yellow
```

This allows you to do:

```
>>> Color.yellow.primary_colors
(Color.red, Color.blue, Color.yellow)
```

If you wanted to, you could add an `is_primary()` property as well:

```
    @property
    def is_primary(self):
        return self in self.primary_colors
```

And then, if you get a `Color` member, do:

```
if some_Color_member.is_primary:
    do_something()
```

---

As of Python 3.9 you can add `classmethod` to `property`:

```
    @classmethod
    @property
    def primary_colors(self):
        return self.red, self.blue, self.yellow
```

which allows calling `primary_colors` on the enum and not just the member:

```
>>> Color.primary_colors
(Color.red, Color.blue, Color.yellow)
```

Comment: Ahhh, that's exactly the sort of thing I needed, thanks!

Comment: @WayneWerner:  After thinking about it, I renamed the `primary` property to `is_primary`.

Comment: `Color.primary_colors` returns a property object, not the actual tuple. It only works on specific enum values, like `Color.red.primary_colors`

Comment: @IvanVirabyan:  Thanks -- I should have tested both code paths. Answer updated for 3.9+ where it can work as I thought it should.  :-)

Comment: Thanks, yeah it works that way, although `mypy` complains about having both `classmethod` and `property`. I went with just `classmethod`.